# How to limit tag_counts items when using acts_as_taggable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, act-as-taggable-on

I'm using the "acts_as_taggable_on" gem on my podcast page.

`tag_counts` shows all tags, using this HAML code:

```
#tag_cloud
    %h3
       = raw Podcast.tag_counts.sort{ |x, y| x.name.upcase <=> y.name.upcase }.map{  |p| link_to p.name, podcasts_path(tag: p.name), remote: true}.join(' ')
```

I think it will display a mess as tags will continuously be created. I want to show only one row and if the tags are over the row, a button will show and visitors can click it to append them all.

Is there a way I can limit items with `tag_counts` in "acts_as_taggable"?

Comment: There is always a way, please update the question with what you actually want to do and you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `first()` in the line that sorts, maps, then joins:

```rb
Podcast.tag_counts.sort { ... }.map { ... }.join(' ')
```

The first part returns an `Array`, and `Array#first` will "limit" the results to 10, in this example:

```rb
Podcast.tag_counts.sort { ... }.map { ... }.first(10).join(' ')
```

In your code, an extremely long line is unwieldy, and you should reorganize or break it up.

Answer (score 1):

That code doesn't belong in the view, you should write a class method in your Podcast class called maybe something like `get_tag_cloud` and have that return the results you want to show in your view.

Of course, you can limit the number of records returned but what logic would you want to limit by?

You could do:

```
class Podcast < ApplicationRecord
  def self.get_tag_cloud
    tag_counts.limit(20).sort{ |x, y| x.name.upcase <=> y.name.upcase }.map{  |p| link_to p.name, podcasts_path(tag: p.name), remote: true}.join(' ')
  end
 
  #...
end
```

Then your view becomes:

```
 = raw Podcast.get_tag_cloud
```

But I don't really think that is what you want. How do you prioritise what tags should be shown and which should be ignored, and if a tag will always be omitted then what is the point of allowing the tag?

You need to sort out your business logic before a more concise answer can be provided.

You really need to ask a different question.

Comment: You're very correct that the code shouldn't be in the view. Views are only responsible for rendering, not looking up or calculating values. Actually, agreed on all counts.

Comment: @theTinMan, Thank you for your comment, my answer is still not strictly correct as the controller should be ensuring an instance variable is available for the view to make use of, however it looks like th OP has got the answer they wanted.